# Сброс выбранных значений select в форме

Tags: javascript, form, select

Здравствуйте.

Есть форма вот такая

```
<form action="..." method="POST" id="myform">
    <select name="name1" id="name1">
      <option value="">Выбрать</option>
      <option value="1">Пункт 1</option>
      ...
    </select>
    <select name="name2" id="name2">
      <option value="">Выбрать</option>
      <option value="1">Пункт 1</option>
      ...
    </select>   
    ...
    <inpit type="submit" value="Поехали" />
```

Вопрос - надо добавить кнопку "Сброс", нажатие на которую сбрасывало бы значения всех select'ов на первоначальное, (т.е. "Выбрать").

Как?

Answer (score 4):

```html
<form id="some-form">
  <select>
    <option>Пункт 1</option>
    <option>Пункт 2</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Пункт 1</option>
    <option>Пункт 2</option>
  </select>
  <button type="reset" from="some-form">reset</button>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Или тоже самое с помощью `javascript` -

```js
let form = document.forms[ 'some-form' ];
form.addEventListener( 'submit', form_submitHandler );

function form_submitHandler( { target } ){
  target.reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="some-form">
  <select>
    <option>Пункт 1</option>
    <option>Пункт 2</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Пункт 1</option>
    <option>Пункт 2</option>
  </select>
  <button type="reset" from="some-form">reset</button>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: А вот нет. При отправке формы происходит перезагрузка страницы, выбранные пункты становятся selected, и кнопка type="reset" не работает.

Comment: @АлександрВладимирович ajax юзаж никак?

Comment: Немного изменил первый вариант и на самый крайний случай добавил вариант с `js`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Добавить кнопку с `id`:

   ```
   <buton id='clear'>clear</buton>
   ```
2. Добавить слушателя на событие нажатия на кнопку, в нём выполнять сброс `select`-ов:

   ```
   $('#clear').click(() => {
       $('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
   })
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function reset() {
  $("select").val("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="..." method="POST" id="myform">
    <select name="name1" id="name1">
      <option value="">Выбрать</option>
      <option value="1">Пункт 1</option>
    </select>
    <select name="name2" id="name2">
      <option value="">Выбрать</option>
      <option value="1">Пункт 1</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Поехали"/>
</form>
<input type="button" value="reset" onclick="reset()"/>
```